# Deserialize hcl with labels

Tags: rust, serde, hcl

I'm attempting to use `hcl-rs = 0.7.0` to parse some HCL. I'm just experimenting with arbitrary HCL, so I'm not looking to parse terraform specific code.

I'd like to be able to parse a block like this and get it's label as part of result

```
nested_block "nested_block_label" {
    foo = 123
}
```

This currently doesn't work, but hopefully it shows my intention. Is something like this possible?

```
#[test]
fn deserialize_struct_with_label() {
    #[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
    struct TestRoot {
        nested_block: TestNested,
    }
    #[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
    struct TestNested {
        label: String,
        foo: u32,
    }


    let input = r#"
    nested_block "nested_block_label" {
        foo = 123
    }"#;
    let expected = TestRoot{ nested_block: TestNested { label: String::from("nested_block_label"), foo: 123 } };
    assert_eq!(expected, from_str::<TestRoot>(input).unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `hcl` by default seems to interpret

```
nested_block "nested_block_label" {
    foo = 123
}
```

as the following "serde structure":

```
"nested_block" -> {
  "nested_block_label" -> {
    "foo" -> 123
  }
}
```

but for your Rust structs, it would have to be

```
"nested_block" -> {
  "label" -> "nested_block_label"
  "foo" -> 123
}
```

I'm not aware of any [attributes](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) that would allow you to bend the former into the latter.

As usual, when faced with this kind of situation, it is often easiest to first deserialize to a generic structure like `hcl::Block` and then convert to whatever struct you want manually. Disadvantage is that you'd have to do that for every struct separately.

You could, in theory, implement a generic deserialization function that wraps the `Deserializer` it receives and flattens the two-level structure you get into the one-level structure you want. But implementing Deserializers requires massive boilerplate. Possibly, somebody has done that before, but I'm not aware of any crate that would help you here, either.

As a sort of medium effort solution, you could have a special `Labelled` wrapper structure that always catches and flattens this intermediate level:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Labelled<T> {
    label: String,
    t: T,
}

impl<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>> Deserialize<'de> for Labelled<T> {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct V<T>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
        impl<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for V<T> {
            type Value = Labelled<T>;
            fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: serde::de::MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                if let (Some((label, t)), None) =
                    (map.next_entry()?, map.next_entry::<String, ()>()?)
                {
                    Ok(Labelled { label, t })
                } else {
                    Err(serde::de::Error::invalid_type(
                        serde::de::Unexpected::Other("Singleton map"),
                        &self,
                    ))
                }
            }
        }
        deserializer.deserialize_map(V::<T>(Default::default()))
    }
}
```

would be used like this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct TestRoot {
    nested_block: Labelled<TestNested>,
}
#[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct TestNested {
    foo: u32,
}
```

Lastly, there may be some trick like adding `#[serde(rename = "$hcl::label")]`. Other serialization libraries (e.g. `quick-xml`) have similar and allow marking fields as something special this way. `hcl-rs` does the same internally, but it's undocumented and I can't figure out from the source whether what you need is possible.